# Term for methods intended to be added dynamically at runtime?

Tags: python

I've been tasked with taking over a large, existing Python program.

The author created a MainClass(), along with many (technically) functions that include a 'self' first argument and are dynamically added to a ExternalClass() that gets imported/instantiated at runtime.

In this large file, it is very easy to confuse the methods of the MainClass() with the dynamic methods of ExternalClass(), especially since the both include a first argument of `self` and are separated only by a few blank lines.

I know I should refactor, but for now my first priority is to keep the program working while I learn more about it.

I have put a comment between the MainClass() methods and the dynamic methods.

*What is the proper term for functions that are intended to be added to another class as methods at runtime?*

I've been using the term "free methods", but that doesn't seem right.

```
class MainClass():
    def __init__(self):...
    def method_1(self):...
    ...
    def method_n(self):...

#
# -- The following [term?] methods are added to ExternalClass() dynamically at runtime
#

def dynamic_method_1(self):...
def dynamic_method_n(self):...
```

Comment: This isn't a common paradigm, I don't think there's a specific word. They're just dynamically-added methods.

Comment: You can call them extension method as other languages like C# and scala call them this way, although the mechanism isn't the same.

Comment: Implementation ?